# Installation of VS 2013 on Windows Server 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-server-2008-r2

Can we Install the VS 2013 on Windows 2008 R2 (32-bit OS). In System requirements, i have seen Windows 2008 R2(64-bit OS) supports the installation of VS 2013.

Am receiveing below pop when i click the setup file on my 32 bit 2008 R2 Server,

"The specified program requires a newer version of Windows".

Kindly Suggest.

Thanks in Advance,

Senthil Arasu.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot as Windows 2008 R2(64-bit OS) is a requirement to support the installation of VS 2013.